# Manjaro linux размытый шрифт в google chrome при высоком dpi (масштабировании)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, шрифты, manjaro

*Manjare Linux* в настройках шрифтов поставил `dpi 120` так как ноутбук экран *fullhd*,
но при этом в chrome шрифты смазываются.

при запуске Chroma

```
google-chrome-stable --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1
```

увеличиваю масштаб страницы на `125%` шрифты не смазываться но при этом шрифт url адреса маленький и не удобна пользоваться, кто нибудь сталкивался такой проблемой есть ли решения?

Answer (score 1):

порыв какие аргументы можно передавать хрому, так вот нашел - disable-font-subpixel-positioning 
(Force disables font subpixel positioning. This affects the character glyph sharpness, kerning, hinting and layout.)

запускаете

google-chrome-stable  --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1.3  --disable-font-subpixel-positioning

можно --force-device-scale-factor=1.2 кому как, чем больше тем масштабнее

и шрифты выглядят четкими на вашем fullhd мониторе ноутбука)